# Hibernate: Saving just the child objects and ignoring Parent Object

Tags: hibernate

I have an object model as:

```
class Parent {
   List<childType1>childList1;
   List<childType2>childList2;
   List<childType3>childList3;
}
```

In database I just have to save child object lists and there is no relationship among children . Can I just call `session.save(ParentObj)` once and hibernate will only save the child data ignoring the parent object?

Else I have to extract each list and call session.save 100 times.

Comment: Why do you expect that calling `save()` on the parent object would ignore the parent object?

Comment: @MattBall You are right. But here I have 3 Lists of child objects and I don't want to call 'save()' for each and every item of these lists.

Comment: Then perhaps you should introduce an intermediate entity which contains nothing other than the entities you _do_ want to save (namely, the 3 lists of children), and just call save on that new intermediate object. To be clear, change `Parent` → 3 lists of `Child`  to `Parent` → new type → 3 lists of `Child`.